# put items of list in separate cells of dataframe

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I've got a list of numpy arrays where a single array looks like this:

```
[array([[-0.8129685 ,  0.25563928,  0.5257286 , ...,  0.27218387,
        -0.09186438,  0.21530187]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.41776586, -0.03817111,  0.8204172 , ...,  0.16926236,
         0.1923414 ,  0.18040611]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.70996654, -0.03073553,  0.74552304, ...,  0.52257764,
        -0.1465849 , -0.38585848]], dtype=float32), array([[-1.0497763 , -0.05266491,  0.69915617, ...,  0.24170516,
         0.05062697,  0.29804927]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.70316374,  0.22170547,  0.47574154, ...,  0.52260965,
        -1.2310463 ,  0.431722  ]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.72455716, -0.05363848,  0.8941862 , ...,  0.05577775,
         0.14195909, -0.0771163 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.45597026,  0.31754223,  0.72948986, ...,  0.40124443,
        -0.52186936,  0.54976016]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.64960825, -0.02850961,  0.79791856, ...,  0.26005346,
        -0.32073644, -0.1945045 ]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.6557834 ,  0.1716764 ,  0.938828  , ...,  1.0849419 ,
        -0.12322052, -0.38584358]], dtype=float32), array([[-0.41776586, -0.03817111,  0.8204172 , ...,  0.16926236,
         0.1923414 ,  0.18040611]], dtype=float32)]
```

i'd like to copy the items of the arrays to a dataframe. I pass this list of arrays as the variable `embeddings` to a dataframe in line four.

this is the code i've got but i don't know how to do it for every item in the list...

```
def createDataFrame(embeddings, data):
    sentences = data['Interest_Name']
    sentences_df = pd.DataFrame(sentences)
    embeddings_df = pd.DataFrame(embeddings) ### don't know how to get the list of arrays right :/
    print(embeddings_df)
    dataframe = sentences_df.join(embeddings_df)

    return dataframe

dataframe = createDataFrame(embeddings, data)
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've edited the question based on the questions asked by @D R

Answer (score 0):

emdeddings are columns's names?
data is given list?
every numpy array is a column in the dataframe?
if I am right then try this:

```
# your given list of arrays
arr = [np.random.rand(5, 1), np.random.rand(5, 1), np.random.rand(5, 1)]
embeddings = list('abc')

arr = np.array(arr)
arr = reshape(3, 5).T
df = pd.DataFrame(arr, columns=embeddings)
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please show how this peace of code should be integrated and used by the OP and explain your solution.

Comment: the embeddings are in the list with arrays that is stated in the first code piece. The data is a list of tensors converted to numpy. Every numpy array should be a row in the df.